# Python OOP with netmiko

Tags: python-3.x, oop, netmiko

Using Netmiko I try to connect to multiple devices(routers, switches etc.). Because I need orchestration, where one device after the other executes commands, I tried to go with objects.

Once finished, I need to open connections to several devices and send them commands to execute. At the end I need to close all connections.

So, here is my class:

```py
    
class Switch:

    def __init__(self, hostname):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.connection = self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            # establish connection
            print(f"Connecting to {self.hostname}...")
            self.connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip=self.hostname, device_type=device_type, username=username,
                                                    password=password)

        # Handle timeout etc.
        except netmiko_exceptions as e:
            failed.append(f"{self.hostname}:{e}")
        except ValueError as v:
            failed.append(f"{self.hostname}:{v}")
        else:
            return self.connection

    def send_command(self, command):
        self.connection.send_command(command)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.disconnect()
```

It is best practice to move the establishing of a connection into a try block, however I want to have `send_command` and `disconnect` seperated.

When I execute the code, I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'Switch' object has no attribute 'send_command'`

Comment: When I add 
`       else:
            return connection`
to the try block, I get the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_command'
send_command is a function of the netmiko connection.

Comment: add correct indentation for methods, because currently they aren't methods of Switch, just plain functions... but maybe this is just  typo

Comment: more important to change `self.connection = netmiko......`

Comment: @Green_Wizard, thanks for your reply. Yes, the indentation was just a typo. I corrected that and added ```self.connection = netmiko...``` But error stays the same ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_command'```

Comment: oh, i see now that you wrote `self.connection = self.connect()`, but didn't return connection in `self.connect()`

Comment: @Green_Wizard: Sorry, for the late reply, I was in vacation. I have figured it out now. Would not have been possible without your help. Thanks!